# find max and its column and row in 2D matrix

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have matrix like this:

```
a = [  2 5 4 7; 1 2 5 8; 2 3 4 5; 4 3 1 5]
```

what is the function to return the maximum and its column and row's index ?

For example, in my case that function should return maximum is 8, and column index is 4, and row index is 2

Comment: have you at least tried `max`? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html also look at `a(:)` and `find`... this is not hard. Please at least attempt it yourself and if you fail, post the code that you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using `max` twice:

```
[m irows]=max(a)
[mm icol]=max(m)
irow=irows(icol)
a(irow,icol)
```

Another solution is to unroll `a` to be a vector with `a(:)`, use `max`, which will give you a single index that you then need to convert to row and column. you can easily figure out how it works by printing `b(:)` with `b=[1,3;2,4]` for instance.

Comment: Why not `[irow, icol] = find(a = max(a(:)))`?

Comment: That's better indeed (if you meant `a==`), I tend to forget that `find` can output row and column. However, I guess I'd just do:
`[m i]=max(a(:))` and `[irow icol]=ind2sub(size(a), i)`

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @yoh.lej, you can use `ind2sub` to convert the output from `find` into co-ordinates:

```
m = magic(5);
[y, i] = max(m(:));
[r, c] = ind2sub(size(m), i)
```